# How to return reactor.core.publisher.ParallelFlux in Graphql?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, graphql-java, graphql-spring-boot

I am trying to fetch users by user ids and my graphqls data is:

```
type Query {
  getUsersById(ids: [string!]: [User]
}

type User{
  name: String!
}
```

Assume the controller returns a response like below:

***Not working code***

```
@QueryMapping("getUsersById")
public ParallelFlux<User> getUserById(@Argument List<String> ids){
   return repository.getParallelFluxUsersInfo(ids); 
}
```

***I am not expecting any workaround*** like return Flux only. I just wanted to check if we can return ParallelFlux as well or not. If yes, how to define the query?
With above code, its throwing an error like below:

```
"Can't resolve value /getUsersById: type mismatch error, expected type List. DataFetchingException."
```

It works if I use Flux, like below.

***Working code***

```
 @QueryMapping("getUsersById")
 public Flux<User> getUserById(@Argument List<String> ids){
    return repository.getFluxUsersInfo(ids); //It works
 }
```